# Getting Please fix errors and re-upload file while csv product import Magento ver. 1.9.2.1

Tags: import, csv, export, magento-1.9.2.1

[image: error]
I am getting below error while product import from admin. As there is no particular error (mostly error in csv formats) i am not able to debug.

File permission of media folder

[image: permission]

In Export of Products i am also getting

[image: export]

I know how to solve this error as per [link to solve export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929329/invalid-entity-model-error-while-exporting-csv-file-for-products-in-magento-1) but why this happen suddenly

**UPDATE 1:**
I checked log file and in log there is error as below
[image: error in log]

but i created a var/tmp folder with 777. still same issue.

Comment: clear /var/log/ /var/session and /var cache. check the permission for var and media folder are correct

Comment: i cleared complete `var` and file permission are 777 to media

Comment: check var/importexport folder is there. also check permission for this

Comment: there is no `importexport` inside `var` after deleting the complete `var folder`

Comment: create importexport in var folder and give full permission and check

Comment: i created var/importexport with 777 and tried to import but same error

Comment: if i use ` $destination = tempnam(Mage::getBaseDir() . '/var/tmp/'  , 'importexport_');` in `/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Adapter.php` i am able to export as previously i did to solve that prblem,       ......... but still import have same issue.